# Transferring CSV data into different Functions in Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

i need some help. Basically, i have to create a function to read a csv file then i have to transfer this data into another function to use the data to generate a xml file.
Here is my code:

```
import csv
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

def read_csv():
    with open ('1250_12.csv', 'r') as data:
         reader = csv.reader(data)
    return reader

def generate_xml(reader):
    root = Element('Solution')
    root.set('version','1.0')
    tree = ElementTree(root)

    head = SubElement(root, 'DrillHoles')
    head.set('total_holes', '238')

    description = SubElement(head,'description')
    current_group = None
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i > 0:
           x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
           if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
                current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

                information = SubElement (current_group, 'hole',{'collar':', '.join((x1,y1,z1)),
                                                   'toe':', '.join((x2,y2,z2)),
                                                   'cost':    cost})
        i+=1

def main():
    reader = read_csv()
    generate_xml(reader)

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

but i get an error when i try to pass reader, the error is: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: please revisit the indentation in the code. At least the last line is indented incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the reader into a list should work:

```
def read_csv():
      with open ('1250_12.csv', 'r') as data:
           return list(csv.reader(data))
```

You tried to read from a closed file. `list` will trigger the reader to read the whole file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Andy Xu\workspace\Python Practice\Practice.py", line 37, in <module>
    if __name__=='__main__': main()
  File "C:\Users\Andy Xu\workspace\Python Practice\Practice.py", line 34, in main
    reader = list(read_csv())
  File "C:\Users\Andy Xu\workspace\Python Practice\Practice.py", line 9, in read_csv
    return list(reader)ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Answer (score 1):

the `with` statement tells python to *clean up* the context manager (in this case, a file) once control exits its body.  Since functions exit when they return, there's no way to get data out of it with the file still open.

Other answers suggest reading the whole thing into a list, and returning that; this works, but may be awkward if the file is very large.

Fortunately, we can use generators:

```
def read_csv():
    with open('1250_12.csv', 'r') as data:
        reader = csv.reader(data)
        for row in reader:
            yield row
```

Since we yield from inside the `with`, we don't have to clean up the file before getting some rows. Once the data is consumed, (or if the generator is itself cleaned up,) the file will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

So when you read a csv file it is very important to put that file into a list. This is because  most operations you cannot perform on the `csv.reader` file, and that if you do, once you loop through it and it is at the end of the file, you can no longer do anything with it unless you open it and read it again. So lets just change your `read_csv` function

```
def read_csv():
    with open ('1250_12.csv', 'r') as data:
         reader = csv.reader(data)
         x = [row for row in reader]
    return x
```

Now you are manipulating a list and everything should work perfectly!